# How to change the UI language of gedit under windows7?

Tags: windows-7, language, gedit, i18n

gedit starts with the system-language of my system but I want to use the US version of the UI.
I can not find a option in the menues or the config-file.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look at the gedit homepage and noticed that it uses gtk. So without having tried this myself I would expect this to work the same as with all the other gtk based applications: simply set the environment variable LANG to the locale you want.

Check out the FAQ of gimp that contains some information that may be of help (its the second entry in there) for doing this in windows.

http://gimp-win.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Answer (score 2):

I renamed the directory for my language (Dutch) in C:\Program Files (x86)\gedit\share\locale from 'nl' to 'NOWAYnl' and restarted. There is probably a better way but this seems to work.

Comment: Works! Here is a "how-to" with screenshots and everything: http://laboinaroja.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/how-to-change-gedits-default-language-to-english/

Comment: Good solution. Bad that gedit developers did not think about it.